# DB2 query for locks and deadlocks

Tags: db2-luw

Is it possible to figure out locks/deadlocks via a query in DB2. During inserts on tables which has installed triggers, locks are made on such tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options:

- administrative views - like [SYSIBMADM.LOCKS_HELD](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-locks-held-locks-held) or [SYSIBMADM.LOCKWAITS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-lockwaits-current-lockwaits)
- [Tablefunctions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=monitoring-locking-using-table-functions)
- [Locking Event Monitor](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=events-lock-deadlock-event-monitoring) (needs to be created and is ment for durable monitoring - esults can be queried with SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Another few methods I found out are,

1. Using db2pd command

> `db2pd -db <database_name> -locks`

[image: Outpoot of db2pd command]

2. Using dsmtop tool

> Start dsmtop tool using the command,
> `dsmtop -d <database_name>`

> Navigate to `View` then navigate to `Locking` then naviget to `Locks`

[image: Output of dsmtop tool]

I hope this helps